# In Quickbook PHP API how to queue up multiple call to same methods using the enqueue()

Tags: php, magento, quickbooks

Currently am using the consolibyte php quickbook api for syncing the magento orders as sales orders in the quickbook desktop using the enqueue()

here the problem when you try to sync multiple orders only the last order was queued up with quickbook to sync and the remaing  order were not syncing

here is my code i was using to queue

```
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance($dsn);
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER,$customerid,'10', $customers);
```

Comment: Is it possible you're performing the same query over and over again? the 6th argument to enqueue is set to `true` which will `replace` any previously duplicate query, if you set to false, does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> here the problem when you try to sync multiple orders only the last order was queued up with quickbook to sync and the remaing order were not syncing

The only way this can happen is if *you tell it to happen*. e.g. *you are telling the framework to only queue up the last order*.

Something like this *will* result in multiple things being queued up, and will work just fine:

```
$order_ids = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );
foreach ($order_ids as $order_id)
{
  $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER, $order_id);
}
```

This:

> $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER,$customerid,'10', $customers);

Makes little to no sense at all without more context. It doesn't make any sense for the following reasons:

1. You're not queueing up orders here, you're queuing up customers. If you're trying to queue up orders, why are you using QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER?
2. What is `$customers` set to?  Why are you setting it?
3. Why are you passing in a string '10'?

If you expect an answer to your question *post the rest of your code* so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
-- before syncing the order i was checking that customer exits in the QB or not if he was not exits then i was creating the user after creating user am syncing the order
-- if user exits then am adding sales order to qb
-- $customers contians the extra data for storeing details in the db and to creating xml to pass the QB
-- by mistake i mentioned in the string

Comment: @murali418 OK, so post your relevant code then. Post the code that shows how you're queueing up the ORDERS. The code for queueing up customers is not relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks fort he reply Keith, here is the url http://mmfashiondesign.com/code.zip for the zip which contains the code please check my code and guide me to solve it -- in the QuickbookController.php file the method i used to quickbook sync is syncAction() -- in the qb folder contain the code of the quickbook

Comment: @murali418 I don't see any calls to queue up any orders in your controller. You should be queueing up the order in your controller with $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER, $order['order_id'], 5);

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Keith, the call to queue up was made in the functions.php file  at line number 452 in the _quickbooks_customer_add_response() method
-- the functions.php file was inside the QB folder 
please check the code and guide to solve the issue 
http://mmfashiondesign.com/code.zip

Comment: That is the wrong place to queue this up. Queue it up in your controller, at the same time you queue up the check to see if the customer exists. Use the priorities to make sure that the check for the customer, and the customer add/update run before the request to add the order. When you queue up the order, MAKE SURE YOU USE THE ORDER ID to queue it up, and NOT THE CUSTOMER ID. $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_ADD_SALESORDER, $the_order_id_goes_here);